# Installing hyperledger sawtooth on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, hyperledger-sawtooth

I have Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. I have Raspbian OS installed on it. I'm trying to install Hyperledger sawtooth on it.  I have used their docker image form here https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/app_developers_guide/docker.html but it didn't work for me and I got this error: **exec user process caused "exec format error"** .

I guess this maybe due to the architecture difference ? I have ARMhf architecture (I checked using dpkg --print-architecture).

I need help installing hyperlegder sawtooth on a raspberry pi

Comment: Since you're running the Sawtooth components as containers, it technically doesn't matter which infrastructure it's running in. It matters if the code has direct dependency on any of the hardware features. The error you're facing could be because of the script you're using as entrypoint. Do you have such custom code with you? Check if that file can be executed on your device, if not that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Thank you soo much for replying me here. 
This is the Docker Compose file for the Sawtooth environment . https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/app_developers_guide/sawtooth-default.yaml .
I'm just running it on my raspberry pi. I have made no changes to the docker file.

Comment: Here is a same issue that I'm facing https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/STL-985 .

It exits with code 1

Comment: Please provide more log traces. Are you using a script to start these containers or run the compose file?

Comment: I have pasted my logs here. Kindly review this https://pastebin.com/fLDjEu7R

Comment: Hi, @AhmadSaeed I am also facing the same problem. Please let me know if you were able to solve this